# Advantages of using application/json over text/plain?

Tags: javascript, java, json, xmlhttprequest, httpwebrequest

Is there any performance advantage of using content type `application/json` sending an object serialized to json over `text/plain`?

I know many frameworks (like Spring) can map and serialize data based on the content type, but in general I find that this process is easy enough that it isn't a compelling reason to use `application/json` over `text/plain` for JSON objects.

Example:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain");
// or
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"}));
```

Comment: Are you just talking about which mime type is specified, or about using json?

Comment: both. I could send the json representation of an object with a plain text content type or with an application json content type.

Comment: I am dissapointed as nobody answered why I would explicitly choose "application/json" instead of "text/plain" as content-type, though json itself is still actually a plain text. I don't choose "application/html" or "application/css" after all, right?

Comment: @Gherman you would use it when you tried sending a request using **text/plain** but got an error, but when you tried **application/json** it worked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's assume that you are talking about using JSON versus a custom format (using MIME type `text/plain`) for passing structured data.

Performance may be broken down into different components; e.g.

- relative time taken to encode the content into the format,
- relative time taken to decode the format to give you the original content, and
- relative size of encoded content.

In theory, we can say that a hypothetical optimally designed and implemented custom format will be no slower or no less dense than JSON.  (The "proof" is obvious.  Choose an optimal implementation of JSON and make some minor change to the format that doesn't affect performance.)

In reality though, you have to compare performance of actual formats and actual implementations.  The answer therefore that the performance really depends on how good a job you do of designing and implementing the format and its associated encoding/decoding software.  Furthermore, it also depends on how you implement JSON.  There are a number of server-side JSON libraries with different performance characteristics, as well as different ways of mapping data from / to "native" data structures.

This brings us to the real advantages of JSON (and XML) over custom formats.

- With JSON and XML, there are libraries available for any mainstream language you chose to use to assist in encoding and decoding content.  With a custom format, you have to roll your own encoding / decoding for the client and server sides.
- With JSON and XML, there are standards that say what is well-formed that allow other people to implement encoders / decoders.  With a custom format, you have to write the specification yourself if you want other people to be able to implement your format.
- JSON and XML have standard ways of dealing with issues like charset encoding and "meta" characters appearing in data.  With a custom you have to understand and address these issues your self.  (And if you don't, you are likely to get into difficulty down the track.)
- Ease of change.  It is a relatively simple matter to evolve a JSON / XML based format.  But with a custom format, you have (at least) got more work to do, and depending on your design choices, it could be very difficult.

For most application, *these issues matter far more than performance*.  And that's why JSON or XML are widely used.

**FOLLOWUP**

> But what if instead you assume that I'm not using a custom implementation and compare sending JSON with a mime type of text/plain to that of mime type application/json?

Then the answer is that it makes **almost no** *performance* difference.

- You save 6 bytes in the HTTP request or response header because the mime type string is shorter, but this is insignificant for typical HTTP messages whose sizes are measured in thousands of bytes.
- Using a "text/plain" content type makes no difference to the work that needs to be done to encode / decode the request or response messages ... apart from the time taken to compare / copy 6 extra bytes, which is probably too small to measure.

In addition, using an inaccurate MIME type is (arguably) a violation of the HTTP specs.  If you do this:

- it is more likely that the receiver will mishandle the response; e.g. fail to decode it, or show it in a browser window, and
- you may break HTTP content type negotiation, assuming that your client or server uses it.

In short, I can think of no *good* reason to do this<sup>1</sup>, and a few *good* reasons not to do it.

---

<sup>1 - In general.  Obviously, there will be edge cases ...</sup>

Comment: But what if instead you assume that I'm not using a custom implementation and compare sending JSON with a mime type of text/plain to that of mime type application/json?

Comment: I've notice that google serves autocomplete suggestions as JSON in txt format. I wonder what they are gaining from it

Comment: Possibly it prevents certain browsers from "rendering" the JSON in contexts where it would be harmful.  Possibly a 6 byte saving is significant when multiplied by billions of requests.  Possibly they are gaining little / nothing ...

Comment: I wondered this when I realized Amazon AWS SNS uses "text/plain" as the content type for HTTPS topic subscribers. "Why aren't they sending this as application/json?"  6 bytes is 6 bytes, though presumably it is just legacy.

Comment: Saving 6 bytes per message could be a significant saving for a service that handles squillions of small HTTP requests/responses per year.    I guess they measured it, and decided it was worth it ... for *their* application.  I don't know.  Ask *them*.

Comment: it seems one might be able to avoid a pre-flight cors request using application/json

Answer (score 13):

JSon is basically a format of plain text. As such it can't be faster than the best plain text format. (It could be faster than a poorly chosen plain text format)  JSon is used because it makes encoding and decoding easier and is fairly human readable for many types of data, esp complex ones.

If you are looking for an alternative to which you are using now, perhaps you could give some more details of the data you are sending and we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I'm not looking for an alternative, it's just like you said, json is a format of plain text, so it can be sent as plain text. I'm just not convinced whether either practice is more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

JSON will eventually become the widely accepted format along with xml. JSON's acceptance is growing pretty quickly, which makes it a smarter choice over text , keeping the future in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the json.org description(LOL) and I couldn't agree more:

> JSON: The Fat-Free Alternative to XML

Here you find there are Json libraries for almost all languages.

http://www.json.org/

Json is so easy with Jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

One of the best texts I've found about Json http://ascherconsulting.com/what/are/the/advantages/of/using/json/

> Because JSON was designed for the
>   purpose of serializing and
>   unserializing data being sent to and
>   from JavaScript applications, the
>   advantages of using JSON relate to the
>   advantages of JSON over other means of
>   serialization.  The most well-known
>   means of serializing data for
>   transmission to and from applications
>   at present is XML.  Yet, XML is a
>   rather cumbersome means of
>   serialization.  First, the sender must
>   encode the data to be serialized based
>   on a document type definition that the
>   recipient understands.  Doing so
>   creates a great deal of extra padding
>   around the actual data no matter which
>   DTD is used.  So, the size of XML
>   documents is often fairly large in
>   comparison with the actual set of
>   values they contain.  Second, the
>   recipient must receive the stream of
>   XML and decode the data in order to
>   then put that data into memory.  In
>   comparison, the serialization of data
>   using JSON by the sender is relatively
>   quick and compact because the
>   structure of JSON reflects the
>   structure of standard programming data
>   types and the encoding mechanism adds
>   only the minimum number of characters
>   required to indicate the structure and
>   value of the data.  Once the recipient
>   receives the JSON serialized data,
>   then, the only processing needing to
>   be done is to evaluate the text of the
>   string using either JavaScript's
>   built-in eval function or a compatible
>   function in another language.  The
>   other standard comparison is YAML,
>   which is able to serialize complex
>   data sets without relying upon a DTD
>   and needs a simpler parser to both
>   read and write than XML.  However,
>   even the simplified YAML parsers
>   generally require more time and
>   generate larger serialized data
>   streams than JSON.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is probably going to be faster because of major optimizations(C code) to JSON-engine. For example V8's JSON.parse() is extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

From other advantages strings JSon formatted are similar javascript Object declaration  so they permit simpler and faster parsing.

JSon string: {name:value name2:value}

Very easy to tranform to javascript Object.