# Best format to send image from javascript client to SQL server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am making an application that will store a Azure SQL server DB user information, including profile photo downloaded from Facebook. On the server side, ASP.NET MVC4'll have a controller that will receive the information and send it to the database.

The client side is Javascript and thought to give the image in json (once converted to base64). Is it a good option? Is it better to directly send the jpg? What are the advantages of sending information in json?

In SQL Server image field would be stored as a nvarchar (max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to return the image as a binary stream content type `image/jpeg` or as a text stream encoded base64? Is far more likely that you're going to do the former, so there is little reason to go through an intermediate base64 encoded transfer. And of course, store them as `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Even *if* you would choose to store them as base64, choosing an Unicode data type for base64 text is really wasteful, (double the storage cost for no reason...), base64 can fit very well in `VARCHAR(max)`.

But, specially in a SQL Azure environemnt, you should consider storing media in [Azure BLOB storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) and store only the Blob path in your database.

Comment: Thank you. If I store only the path in the database, the size stored in the Blob Storage, how you bill? Where is stored? Could different access Web or Worker instances to the data?

Comment: Storage pricing (including Blob) at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/ There ar emore details how to use at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better sending the image directly in .jpg using Multipart Forms or something like that.

Sending information in Json is useful when you transfer explicit data, like collections or objects that you will be able to query or de-serialize later.

Answer (score 0):

> The client side is Javascript and thought to give the image in json (once converted to base64). Is it a good option?

As Pasrus pointed out, you are not going to manipulate the image data. So JSON does not seems to be a good choice here.

One option is, you can add the base64 data into src attribute in html  tag and send it.

> What are the advantages of sending information in json?

Please check this answers and there are so many:

[Advantages of using application/json over text/plain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350753/advantages-of-using-application-json-over-text-plain)

> In SQL Server image field would be stored as a nvarchar (max)

Please refer this link:

[Storing images in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/what-about-storing-images-in-sql-server)