# Which data format for RESTful POST requests?

Tags: rest, http, django-rest-framework, http-headers

Which encrypt value for request POST header when designing a RESTful API for an SPA application?

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain
- application/json

Comment: What motivates this choice and how that would help me over other choices ?

Comment: All of them can be good choices, depending on your needs. JSON is probably a good default, but there is a place for others too.

Answer (score 1):

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the body of the HTTP message
>   sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value
>   pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from
>   values by the equals symbol (=)

([application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data))

- multipart/form-data

> With this method of transmitting name/value pairs, each pair is
>   represented as a "part" in a MIME message
>   -For short alphanumeric values (like most web forms), the overhead of adding all of the MIME headers is going to significantly outweigh any
>   savings from more efficient binary encoding

([application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data))

- text/plain

> This is "not reliably interpretable by computer", so it should never
>   be used in production, and we will not look further into it.

([What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean))

- application/json
  In short, it is sort of a industry standard now. It provides a lot of advantages like flexibility and performance. As well as being universally understandable and descriptive.
  But read the post from [Stephan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) who is way more informed:
  [Advantages of using application/json over text/plain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350753/advantages-of-using-application-json-over-text-plain)

Answer (score 1):

JSON yes, application/json ... not so much. If you just use application/json, your payloads aren't self-descriptive, after all - so you still have strong coupling between both endpoints. Thus, I would recommend to define JSON based media types for each type of message.

Comment: which difference between json and application/json ?

Comment: clarified the response; the problem is that the media type "application/json" is completely generic thus not self-descriptive. Use a more specific one.