# Why starts the mimetype of a JSON with application?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, mime-types

Why is the mimetype for a JSON file `application/json` not `text/json`? It would make much more sense because a JSON is a text file. A JSON file can be opened by a normal text editor like `vim`. So why starts the mimetype of a JSON with `application/`? I thought that `application/*` means the the file cannot be read as text.

Comment: Maybe it will help you [Advantages of using application/json over text/plain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350753/advantages-of-using-application-json-over-text-plain)

Comment: Why should you use it? because it is standardized. Why has it been standardized this way? I don't know. I'd guess it is because the format isn't meant to be read by humans but rather by applications, but that's true of XML too which has both text/xml and application/xml as standardized MIME types

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question, Aaron.