# nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string/ Multipart file and json data to spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I have the `POST` request API call to accept the `JSON` body request parameters and multipart file from the client side. This is my method:

```
@PostMapping("/saveCategory")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void createCategory( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("cateogry") CategoryModel category) {
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName).toUriString();
        //category.setImage_path(fileName);

        //this.categoryRepository.save(category);

        // return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
        // file.getContentType(), file.getSize());

    }
```

I have this exception:

```
 "category_name": "ziska111"

    }'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{"category_name":"ziska111"}"]
```

This is my Postman request:
[image]

I think I have a problem with my `CategoryModel`  but I do not know why:
This is my CategoryModel:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Category")
   @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String category_name;
private String category_description;
private String image_path;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "category")
private Set<ProductModel> category;
+Geterrs and Setters
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to convert string to integer but,  input string contains alphabetical characters and it's impossible to convert to integer

Comment: Hmm, how I can to send an object from my postman, not String?

Comment: As I can see from your screen shot, you have selected category as text but you're passing data as Json. That might be the issue. Please check In the meantime, you can check the difference between two here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350753/advantages-of-using-application-json-over-text-plain